# Origin of the Fourier transform (1878)

Tags: mathematics, physics, 19th-century, fourier, harmonic-analysis

I located Joseph Fourier's book, *Analytical Theory of Heat* (1878), but at first glance it looks like it is all about heat. What did Fourier call the Fourier transform? When did he first use it?

Comment: If you intend to pursue historical issues, then you need to be a bit more nuanced than saying something like Fourier's 1878 book.

Comment: Probably the place you want to look is [**Joseph Fourier 1768–1830**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0262571781) by Ivor Grattan-Guinness, which gives a very detailed analysis of Fourier's 1807 paper, later expanded in 1811 for a prize competition (but not published), and revised and expanded again as a book published in 1822. I believe the Fourier integral did not appear in the 1807 paper, but it did appear in the 1811 manuscript. But I don't have time now to track all this down more thoroughly, so if no one else says much more, then I recommend getting a copy of the book I cited.

Comment: Fourier transform is introduced in this book.

Comment: He wrote it as a combination of sine and cosine transforms. It's in the last chapter of [the book](https://www3.nd.edu/~powers/ame.20231/fourier1878.pdf), article 418ff. Perhaps, you should first read modern commentary, like [Highlights in the History of the Fourier Transform](https://www.embs.org/pulse/articles/highlights-in-the-history-of-the-fourier-transform/), that explains it in modern notation.

Comment: Fourier elaborated the **Fourier Series** for the purpose of the theory of heat. It has been rigorously defined later on (all the 19th century). The **Fourier transform** is something quite different, elaborated by Wiener in the 1930s,... Truely speaking, there is a larger theory gathering Fourier series (for periodic functions) and Fourier transform.